# WPF4 Datagrid doesn't sort on column headers

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

I am trying to implement my first WPF application using an MVVM design pattern.

I created an application that is databinding to an ObservableCollection<>.  The application renders fine, but I expect the datagrid to re-sort the rows when I click on the column headers.

I've researched posts that said:
The data source has to implement IEnumerable, mine does.
I need to set CanUserSortColumns and/or CanUserSort (on each column), I did.
I could implement a custom sort by specifying the Sorting callback function, I did.

None of these seem to have helped. In the debugger, my _customerGrid_Sorting function never gets called and clicking on the column headers has no effect.

Am I missing something in the XAML that follows? Is there another interface I need to implement?  I am feeling very lost right now, so any help is appreciated.

XAML:

```
        <DataGrid Name="_customerGrid" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource columnHeaderStyle}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllCustomers}" 
            RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
            RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
            SelectionUnit="FullRow"
            Sorting="_customerGrid_Sorting"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cust ID" MinWidth="90" CanUserSort="True" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=CustID}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="300" CanUserSort="True" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is this code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cust ID" MinWidth="90" CanUserSort="True" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=CustID}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The default sorting works as stated everywhere only for DataGridTextColumn, DataGridComboBoxColumn,etc. 
Now here the grid does not know how to sort because you have defined a DataTemplate and a Label inside it. Some other person might have defines a SstackTemplate, etc inside DataTemplate.  So the DataGrid will not know how to sort it.

I will try to post you a sample code very soon as what we can do for such DataGridTemplateColumn. But hope the direction I have given you helps!!

---

**Seems that the answer is very simple. I tried it with a sample DataGrid using MVVM but my solution should work for you i feel**

Everything is fine in the below DataGridTemplateColumn but you are missing a very important attribute called **SortMemberPath**. Thw WPF should know on which property it should sort.

The original one which you posted looks like this

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="300" CanUserSort="True" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I dont know your data structures. But the modified one should look like this

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn  SortMemberPath="Name" Header="Name" MinWidth="300" CanUserSort="True" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I hope it helps you!! Let me know if it does not help you, I will try to post my application in some blog ( I am lazy to do it though !!)

Comment: Thanks Guru, that helps a little.  At least I know why the default sort behavior doesn't work.  I take it that means I need to implement a custom sort.  Which I thought I could do by specifying a handler in the Sorting attribute of the DataGrid. But my handler doesn't fire.  I look forward to receiving your code sample to give me more direction.

Comment: @Paul - I think you were just missing an attribute called "SortMemberPath". Hope it helps!!

Comment: Great answer Guru! Thank you for your help!  I will add that by specifying the SortMemberPath="CustID" (for instance) on the DataGridTemplateColumn, I was able to eliminate the Sorting attribute on the DataGrid and remove my custom implementation of IComparer.  I your answer helps others.  If anyone has questions about the solution, I'll try to help them.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a lot of time.  I have to implement CellTemplates for rows where I need text to wrap and actually thought you couldn't sort these columns but now I know you can!

Comment: I have a similar issue, but my DataGrid stopped sorting when I replaced the underlying collection with a BindingList<T>.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one: SortMemberPath="Complete"

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CustID" SortMemberPath="Complete" MinWidth="90"      
CanUserSort="True" CanUserResize="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=CustID}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: How is your answer different than the accepted answer? The value of SortMemberPath should name a column of the datasource. "Complete" is not one of my member columns.

Comment: I didn't see the above answer, may be he/she posted while I was editing mine.  Regarding the header name, I tried it my wpf test, if it work you need just to change the header name.