# CanUserSortColumns in datagrid doesn't make effect?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a datagrid with binding item source. I have set CanUserSortColumns property of datagrid into TRUE and so do with all inner columns in datagrid but user still doesn't be able to sort columns.

Is there something I have missed ?

Comment: show us your xaml binding and your datasource type

Answer (score 4):

Are you explicitly defining `DataTemplate` for your headers? In case yes you have to set property on your column `"SortMemberPath"` to your CLR property on which you want to sort your column. This link might prove helpful to you, have a look at it -

[WPF4 Datagrid doesn't sort on column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859712/wpf4-datagrid-doesnt-sort-on-column-headers)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. That worked. I just want to add.

The types of those columns must implement the non-generic `IComparable`, which is usually not a problem if you are using primitive or .net types. But if you have your own types, then you will have to add it.

E.g.

```
/* this is my own type */
public struct Distance : ..., IComparable, IComparable<Distance>, ... {

    ...

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) { return 1; }

        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Distance)) { return 0; }

        return CompareTo((Distance)obj);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Distance other) { return _meters.CompareTo(other._meters); }
}
```