# Can sorting a wpf datagrid with validation rules?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, validationrules

I have a datagrid with validation rules.
But I can not sort the grid on a column that contains a validation rule

Is it possible to sort a datagrid that contains validation rules?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, the validation rules don't affect sorting at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: SortMemberPath="Complete"

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CustID" SortMemberPath="Complete" MinWidth="90"    CanUserSort="True" CanUserResize="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=CustID}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem in sorting data grid column having validation rules as they are meant only to validate the data. 
Specify the data what you are trying to sort containing validation rules.

Comment: If this not the validation rules, I'm investigate in datagrid template.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we (I'm the co-developer) missed sort information since we are using datagrid columns templates : [WPF4 Datagrid doesn't sort on column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859712/wpf4-datagrid-doesnt-sort-on-column-headers)

It was indeed the cause of non sortable columns.